# Is Azure Synapse is a good choice for Time Series Data?

Tags: azure, time-series, azure-synapse

We are in the process of analyzing which database will be the best choices for Time Series data (like stock market data / trading data, market sentiments ..etc.)

Is Azure Synapse is a good choice for Time Series Data?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Synapse data explorer (Preview) provides you with a dedicated query engine optimized and built for log and time series data workloads.

With this new capability now part of Azure Synapse's unified analytics platform, you can easily access your machine and user data to surface insights that can directly improve business decisions.

To complement the existing SQL and Apache Spark analytical runtimes, Azure Synapse data explorer is optimized for efficient log analytics, using powerful indexing technology to automatically index structured, semi-structured, and free-text data commonly found in telemetry data.

For more info please refer to below related articles:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/data-explorer/data-explorer-overview
2. [Time series solution - Azure Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/scenarios/time-series)

Please note that the feature is in public preview.